# SQL Server automate Create Job Script

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio I can right-click a job, Script job as, and then save the created script as a .sql file.
In order to back up my jobs, I would like to automate the above process, but cannot find any way of doing so.
Is this possible? How?

Comment: Some decent answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361163/automatically-create-scripts-for-all-sql-server-jobs). A new one this month mentions dbatools.io as well.

Comment: Please check this link if it can help you https://serverfault.com/questions/14499/backing-up-and-restoring-sql-server-scheduled-jobs

Comment: Don't overlook @JacobH comment if you are into PowerShell. dbatools is pretty awesome

Comment: @RahulNeekhra you don't *have* to restore it to get the jobs back, but it is certainly the smartest method.

Comment: @JacobH, Thanks! I installed dbatools, and with 3 lines of code I now have a daily script to recreate the job! Could not be simpler!

Comment: No problem! I can't take too much credit. @Kin deserves most of it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from backing up the `msdb` database, which is where they are stored, you could script them out once, and then check for changes every day. If there are no changes, there isn't any reason to back them up again. If you did figure out someone changed a job or a schedule, I'm sure you **next** question would be *what* actually changed and *when* it changed. Otherwise, you wouldn't know which version of your job to restore to.

I wrote a procedure a while back to do just this. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/scsimon/sqlserver/blob/master/usp_sql_agent_job_changes) because it's too long to post here. One dependency of this script is that it logs the *current* jobs, schedules, etc to a table in a database called `AdminTools`. This is so we can compare what is in `msdb` to what we have logged. You can change this to use any database you want to put your logging table.

Also, I wrote a script to do the same thing for Agent Alerts. It can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/scsimon/sqlserver/blob/master/usp_sql_agent_alert_changes).

Here is the *guts* of the agent job procedure, which pulls all the jobs and schedules, and displays it very similarly to SSMS (hence all the logic in the `case` statements).

```
select
        jobs.job_id
        ,job_name = jobs.name
        ,job_desc = jobs.description
        ,jobs.enabled
        ,jobs.date_created
        ,jobs.date_modified
        ,jobs.version_number
        ,jobs.start_step_id                     --ID of the step in the job where execution should begin
        ,job_owner = serv_princ.name            --Security identifier number (SID) of the job owner, to check if job now owned by SA --need to work on this
        ,notify_level_eventlog =    case
                                        when jobs.notify_level_eventlog = 0 then 'Never'
                                        when jobs.notify_level_eventlog = 1 then 'When the job succeeds'
                                        when jobs.notify_level_eventlog = 2 then 'When the job fails'
                                        when jobs.notify_level_eventlog = 3 then 'When the job completes (regardless of outcome)'
                                    end
        ,notify_level_email =   case
                                    when jobs.notify_level_email = 0 then 'Never'
                                    when jobs.notify_level_email = 1 then 'When the job succeeds'
                                    when jobs.notify_level_email = 2 then 'When the job fails'
                                    when jobs.notify_level_email = 3 then 'When the job completes (regardless of outcome)'
                                end
        ,email_operator_name = emailop.name
        ,email_operator_email = emailop.email_address
        ,email_operator_enabled = emailop.enabled
        ,level_page =   case
                            when jobs.notify_level_page = 0 then 'Never'
                            when jobs.notify_level_page = 1 then 'When the job succeeds'
                            when jobs.notify_level_page = 2 then 'When the job fails'
                            when jobs.notify_level_page = 3 then 'When the job completes (regardless of outcome)'
                        end
        ,page_operator_name = pageop.name
        ,page_operator_address = pageop.pager_address
        ,page_operator_enabled = pageop.enabled
        ,page_operator_scheduled_days = SUBSTRING(
                                                      CASE WHEN pageop.pager_days &  1 =  1 THEN ',Sun' ELSE '' END
                                                    + CASE WHEN pageop.pager_days &  2 =  2 THEN ',Mon' ELSE '' END
                                                    + CASE WHEN pageop.pager_days &  4 =  4 THEN ',Tues' ELSE '' END
                                                    + CASE WHEN pageop.pager_days &  8 =  8 THEN ',Wed' ELSE '' END
                                                    + CASE WHEN pageop.pager_days & 16 = 16 THEN ',Thurs' ELSE '' END
                                                    + CASE WHEN pageop.pager_days & 32 = 32 THEN ',Fri' ELSE '' END
                                                    + CASE WHEN pageop.pager_days & 64 = 64 THEN ',Sat' ELSE '' END
                                                , 2, 64)

        ,page_operator_weekday_sked = stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(pageop.weekday_pager_start_time as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':') + ' - ' + stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(pageop.weekday_pager_end_time as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':')
        ,page_operator_saturday_sked = stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(pageop.saturday_pager_start_time as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':') + ' - ' + stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(pageop.saturday_pager_end_time as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':')
        ,page_operator_sunday_sked = stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(pageop.sunday_pager_start_time as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':') + ' - ' + stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(pageop.sunday_pager_end_time as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':')
        ,steps.step_id
        ,steps.step_name
        ,steps.command
        ,on_success_action =    case
                                    when steps.on_success_action = 1 then 'Quit reporting success'
                                    when steps.on_success_action = 2 then 'Quit reporting failure'
                                    when steps.on_success_action = 3 then 'Go to next step (' + cast(steps.step_id + 1 as varchar) + ')'
                                    when steps.on_success_action = 4 then 'Go to step: ' + cast(on_fail_step_id as varchar)
                                end
        ,on_fail_action =   case
                                    when steps.on_fail_action = 1 then 'Quit reporting success'
                                    when steps.on_fail_action = 2 then 'Quit reporting failure'
                                    when steps.on_fail_action = 3 then 'Go to next step (' + cast(steps.step_id + 1 as varchar) + ')'
                                    when steps.on_fail_action = 4 then 'Go to step: ' + cast(on_fail_step_id as varchar)
                                end
        ,last_run_outcome = case
                                when steps.last_run_outcome = 0 then 'Failed'
                                when steps.last_run_outcome = 1 then 'Succeeded'
                                when steps.last_run_outcome = 2 then 'Retry'
                                when steps.last_run_outcome = 3 then 'Canceled'
                                when steps.last_run_outcome = 5 then 'Unknown'
                            else 'Undefined'
                            end
        ,last_run_date = case when steps.last_run_date = 0 then 'Never' else stuff(stuff(steps.last_run_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') end 
        ,last_run_time = stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(steps.last_run_time as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':')
        ,last_run_duration = stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(steps.last_run_duration as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':')
    from 
        msdb.dbo.sysjobs jobs
    left join
        msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps steps on
        steps.job_id = jobs.job_id
    left join
        msdb.dbo.sysoperators emailop on
        emailop.id = jobs.notify_email_operator_id
    left join
        msdb.dbo.sysoperators pageop on
        pageop.id = jobs.notify_email_operator_id
    left join
        sys.server_principals serv_princ on
        serv_princ.sid = jobs.owner_sid


    select 
        sched.schedule_uid
        ,sched.schedule_id
        ,job_name = jobs.name
        ,job_enabled = jobs.enabled
        ,schedule_name = sched.name
        ,schedule_frequency =   case
                                    when sched.freq_type =   1 then 'One time only on ' 
                                                                    + stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') 
                                                                    + ' at ' 
                                                                    + case when sched.active_start_time = 0 then '00:00:00' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end 
                                    when sched.freq_type =   4 then 'Every ' 
                                                                    + cast(sched.freq_interval as varchar) 
                                                                    + ' days,'  
                                                                    +   case 
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 1 then ' at '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 2 then ' every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' seconds, from '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 4 then ' every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' minutes, from '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 8 then ' every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' hours, from '
                                                                        end
                                                                    +   case 
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 1 then case 
                                                                                                                    when sched.active_start_time = 0 then '00:00:00'
                                                                                                                    else stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':')
                                                                                                                 end
                                                                            else
                                                                                case when sched.active_start_time = 0 then '00:00:00' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end
                                                                                + ' - '
                                                                                + case when sched.active_end_time = 0 then '00:00:00'else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end
                                                                        end
                                                                    + ' beginning ' 
                                                                    + stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')
                                                                    + ' and ending '
                                                                    + case when sched.active_end_date = 99991231 then 'Never' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') end
                                    when sched.freq_type =   8 then 'Every ' 
                                                                    + cast(sched.freq_recurrence_factor as varchar) 
                                                                    + ' weeks on ' 
                                                                    + SUBSTRING(
                                                                                  CASE WHEN sched.freq_interval &  1 =  1 THEN ',Sun' ELSE '' END
                                                                                + CASE WHEN sched.freq_interval &  2 =  2 THEN ',Mon' ELSE '' END
                                                                                + CASE WHEN sched.freq_interval &  4 =  4 THEN ',Tues' ELSE '' END
                                                                                + CASE WHEN sched.freq_interval &  8 =  8 THEN ',Wed' ELSE '' END
                                                                                + CASE WHEN sched.freq_interval & 16 = 16 THEN ',Thurs' ELSE '' END
                                                                                + CASE WHEN sched.freq_interval & 32 = 32 THEN ',Fri' ELSE '' END
                                                                                + CASE WHEN sched.freq_interval & 64 = 64 THEN ',Sat' ELSE '' END
                                                                            , 2, 64)
                                                                    +   case 
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 1 then ' at '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 2 then ', every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' seconds, from '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 4 then ', every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' minutes, from '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 8 then ', every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' hours, from '
                                                                        end
                                                                    +   case 
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 1 then case 
                                                                                                                    when sched.active_start_time = 0 then '00:00:00'
                                                                                                                    else stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':')
                                                                                                                 end
                                                                            else
                                                                                case when sched.active_start_time = 0 then '00:00:00' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end
                                                                                + ' - '
                                                                                + case when sched.active_end_time = 0 then '00:00:00'else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end
                                                                        end
                                                                    + ' beginning ' 
                                                                    + stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')
                                                                    + ' and ending '
                                                                    + case when sched.active_end_date = 99991231 then 'Never' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') end
                                    when sched.freq_type =  16 then 'Every ' 
                                                                    + cast(sched.freq_recurrence_factor as varchar) 
                                                                    + ' months, on day ' 
                                                                    + cast(sched.freq_interval as varchar) 
                                                                    + ' of that month,'
                                                                    +   case 
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 1 then ' at '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 2 then ' every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' seconds, from '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 4 then ' every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' minutes, from '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 8 then ' every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' hours, from '
                                                                        end
                                                                    +   case 
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 1 then case 
                                                                                                                    when sched.active_start_time = 0 then '00:00:00'
                                                                                                                    else stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':')
                                                                                                                 end
                                                                            else
                                                                                case when sched.active_start_time = 0 then '00:00:00' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end
                                                                                + ' - '
                                                                                + case when sched.active_end_time = 0 then '00:00:00'else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end
                                                                        end
                                                                    + ' beginning ' 
                                                                    + stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')
                                                                    + ' and ending '
                                                                    + case when sched.active_end_date = 99991231 then 'Never' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') end
                                    when sched.freq_type =  32 then 'Every '
                                                                    +   case
                                                                            when sched.freq_relative_interval = 1 then 'first '
                                                                            when sched.freq_relative_interval = 2 then 'second '
                                                                            when sched.freq_relative_interval = 4 then 'third '
                                                                            when sched.freq_relative_interval = 8 then 'fourth '
                                                                            when sched.freq_relative_interval = 16 then 'last '
                                                                            else ''
                                                                        end
                                                                    +   case 
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval =  1 then 'Sunday'
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval =  2 then 'Monday'
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval =  3 then 'Tuesday'
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval =  4 then 'Wednesday'
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval =  5 then 'Thursday'
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval =  6 then 'Friday'
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval =  7 then 'Saturday'
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval =  8 then 'day'
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval =  9 then 'weekday'
                                                                            when sched.freq_interval = 10 then 'weekend'
                                                                        end 
                                                                    + ', of every ' 
                                                                    + cast(sched.freq_recurrence_factor as varchar)
                                                                    + ' months,'
                                                                    +   case 
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 1 then ' at '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 2 then ' every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' seconds, from '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 4 then ' every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' minutes, from '
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 8 then ' every ' + cast(sched.freq_subday_interval as varchar) + ' hours, from '
                                                                        end
                                                                    +   case 
                                                                            when sched.freq_subday_type = 1 then case 
                                                                                                                    when sched.active_start_time = 0 then '00:00:00'
                                                                                                                    else stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':')
                                                                                                                 end
                                                                            else
                                                                                case when sched.active_start_time = 0 then '00:00:00' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end
                                                                                + ' - '
                                                                                + case when sched.active_end_time = 0 then '00:00:00'else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end
                                                                        end
                                                                    + ' beginning ' 
                                                                    + stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')
                                                                    + ' and ending '
                                                                    + case when sched.active_end_date = 99991231 then 'Never' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') end
                                    when sched.freq_type =  64 then 'When SQL Server Agent service starts beginning ' 
                                                                    + stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')
                                                                    + ' and ending '
                                                                    + case when sched.active_end_date = 99991231 then 'Never' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') end
                                    when sched.freq_type = 128 then 'When computer is idle beginning '
                                                                    + stuff(stuff(sched.active_start_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')
                                                                    + ' and ending '
                                                                    + case when sched.active_end_date = 99991231 then 'Never' else stuff(stuff(sched.active_end_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') end
                                end
        ,next_run_date =    case 
                                when sched.freq_type =  64 and sched.enabled = 1 then 'When SQL Server Agent service starts' 
                                when sched.freq_type = 128 and sched.enabled = 1 then 'When computer is idle'
                            else 
                                case when jobsched.next_run_date = 0 then 'Never' else stuff(stuff(jobsched.next_run_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') end 
                            end
        ,next_run_time =    case 
                                when sched.freq_type =  64 and sched.enabled = 1 then 'When SQL Server Agent service starts' 
                                when sched.freq_type = 128 and sched.enabled = 1 then 'When computer is idle'
                            else 
                                case when jobsched.next_run_date = 0 then 'Never' else case when jobsched.next_run_time = 0 then '00:00:00' else stuff(stuff(jobsched.next_run_time,3,0,':'),6,0,':') end end
                            end
        ,schedule_enabled = sched.enabled
        ,sched.version_number
        ,sched.date_created
        ,sched.date_modified
    from
        msdb.dbo.sysschedules sched
    inner join 
        msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules jobsched on
        jobsched.schedule_id = sched.schedule_id
    inner join
        msdb.dbo.sysjobs jobs on
        jobs.job_id = jobsched.job_id
```

Answer (score 1):

SMO objects through C# can be used to create scripts with the DDL of SQL Agent jobs.  An example of this is below.  References to both the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` and `System.Collections.Specialized` (if using `StringCollection`) namespaces are necessary.  To have this automated, create an SSIS package that has this as a Script Task, and execute the package as a job from SQL Agent.  If any of your jobs have a `\` in the title, this will need to be removed to avoid invalid file paths and the `Replace` method can be added to the Name property of the job below to do this.

```
            Server srv = new Server(@"YourSQLServer");
            srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
            srv.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 600;
            srv.ConnectionContext.Connect();

            Scripter script = new Scripter(srv);
            ScriptingOptions scriptOpt = new ScriptingOptions();

            foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job j in srv.JobServer.Jobs)
            {
                scriptOpt.FileName = @"C:\FolderPathForScripts\" + j.Name + ".sql";
                StringCollection sc = j.Script(scriptOpt);
                foreach (string s in sc)
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
```