# PowerShell code to script out all SQL Server Agent jobs into a single file

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sql-agent-job

I was trying to script out all the SQL Server Agent jobs for category 'Data Warehouse' **into a single file**

I was able to do it using PowerShell, where every single job creates a single file.

But I need one file for all the SQL Server Agent jobs under category ID = 100 (or Category : = 'Data Warehouse')

Code I'm currently using:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo') | Out-Null
$serverInstance = "APAAUHC7DB01VD"

$server = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $serverInstance

$jobs = $server.JobServer.Jobs 
#$jobs = $server.JobServer.Jobs | where-object {$_.category -eq "100"}

if ($jobs -ne $null)
{

$serverInstance = $serverInstance.Replace("\", "-")

ForEach ( $job in $jobs )
{
$FileName = "C:\SQLBackup\SQLJobs\" + $serverInstance + "_" + $job.Name + ".sql"
$job.Script() | Out-File -filepath $FileName
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically create scripts for all SQL Server Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361163/automatically-create-scripts-for-all-sql-server-jobs)

Comment: Nope.. the code they mentioned created multiple files. I want all the sql agent job scripts into a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `$FileName` a single file name for the whole set. Then you can **leave out the whole `foreach` block**:

```
$FileName = "C:\SQLBackup\SQLJobs\whatever.sql"

$jobs | %{ $_.Script() } | Out-File -filepath $FileName
```

Comment: Hi [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo') | Out-Null
$serverInstance = "APAAUHC7DB01VD"

$server = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $serverInstance

$jobs = $server.JobServer.Jobs 
#$jobs = $server.JobServer.Jobs | where-object {$_.category -eq "100"}

if ($jobs -ne $null)
{

$serverInstance = $serverInstance.Replace("\", "-")

ForEach ( $job in $jobs )
{
$FileName = "C:\SQLBackup\SQLJobs\" + $serverInstance + ".sql"
$jobs | { $_.Script() } | Join-String -Separator "`r`n`t" | Out-File -filepath $FileName
}
}

Comment: I changed the code like below : However i get the below error: job step received an error at line 17 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is '$jobs | { $_.Script() } | Join-String -Separator "`r`n`t" | Out-File -filepath $FileName  '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'At line:17 char:9  + $jobs | { $_.Script() } | Join-String -Separator "`r`n`t" | Out-File  ...  +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed. I'm really bad with PowerShell

Comment: Leave out the foreach completely. Have edited, please try again.